# How should I get the Outer Function Variable in the Inner Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following code does not print anything:

```py
class Special:
    def __init__(self, New_ced_file):
        self.new_ced_file = new_ced_file
    
    def compareParameter(self):
        Input = pd.read_csv(new_ced_file, low_memory=False)
        MG = pd.DataFrame({RF1: [1,2,3], 'RD2: '[4,5,6]})
        def MG_data():
            for i, j in Input.iterrows():
                print (j) **#it does not print anything** 
                for k,l in MG.iterrows():
                    print (l) **#it does not print anything** 
    
    new_ced_file = os.path.realpath('///') #filepath
    myobject = Special(new_ced_file)
    myobject.compareParameter()
```

How should I call the outer function variable into an inner function?

Comment: result = MG_data(Input, MG)

Comment: Well, you *actually need to call that function*. But why define an inner function to begin with?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean? Do you mean "how to call outer function from inner function" or the other way around? You can do both by just making the call. Also please adjust the code so that it compiles / emits even something reasonable in a minimal fashion

Comment: @EdvardM I want to called outter function into inner function.

Comment: Sorry, but that still is not clear. There's a context / scope where you can call a function in a given language. You can call the nested / inner function in the method you have _after_ you have defined the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the inner function from the outer function, and pass the variables to the inner function:

```py
class Special:
  def __init__(self, New_ced_file):
    self.new_ced_file = new_ced_file

  def compareParameter(self):
    Input = pd.read_csv(new_ced_file, low_memory=False)
    MG = pd.DataFrame({'RF1': [1,2,3], 'RD2: '[4,5,6]})
    def MG_data(Input, MG):
        for i, j in Input.iterrows():
            print(j)
            for k,l in MG.iterrows():
                print(l)
    result = MG_data(Input, MG) 

new_ced_file = (r'\\\') #filepath
myobject = Special(new_ced_file)
myobject.CompareParameter()
```

Also, if you are using `\` in a string, either:

- Add an r in front of the string: `r'\'`,
- Or use another backslash to cancel the backslash out: `'\\'` (turns into one backslash)

Answer (score 1):

There's various typos in your code which will result in bugs or unexpected behavior.

I can't imaging your code working, so please include any error you're getting in your question so we can help you more efficiently.

- `__init__` should have two underscores on both sides.
- The `New_ced_file` argument for the `__init__` call should match the variable used in the method
- `Input` is really similar to the built-in `input` which is not recommended
- You reference `new_ced_file` in `compareParameter` but should use `self.new_ced_file` instead
- `RF1` should be quoted: `'RF1'`
- assigning to `result` won't do anything, use `return MG_data(Input, MG)` instead
- Also, if you are using \ in a string, either:

  - Add an r in front of the string: `r'\'`
  - Or use another backslash to cancel the backslash out: `'\\'` (turns into one backslash)

Comment: also, he used `'\\\'`, when he should done `r'\\\'`

Comment: Ah, missed that one

Comment: :) yes, I only saw it because the highlighting was weird

Comment: Funny, you answered and closed the question

Comment: I know, there wasn't enough room in the comments to give a proper reply but I wanted to highlight the issues in the code anyway. Feel free to downvote since technically it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nonlocal` keyword to use outer function variable in inner function

```
class Special:
  def __init__(self, New_ced_file):
    self.new_ced_file = new_ced_file

  def compareParameter(self):
    Input = pd.read_csv(new_ced_file, low_memory=False)
    MG = pd.DataFrame({'RF1': [1,2,3], 'RD2: '[4,5,6]})
    def MG_data():
        nonlocal Input, MG
        for i, j in Input.iterrows():
            print(j)
            for k,l in MG.iterrows():
                print(l)

new_ced_file = (r'\\\') #filepath
myobject = Special(new_ced_file)
myobject.CompareParameter()
```

Comment: I used nonlocal and still did not print anything